# Building Pentaho Platform User-Console from source code

Tags: ant, build, pentaho

I had cloned pentaho-platform from github. Been trying to build the source code.
Other projects got build successful, but when trying to build the pentaho-user-console, I got failed.

I have downloaded pentaho-platform 5.4 branch, and when trying to build it using
`ant clean-all resolve create-dot-classpath publish-local`, I've got this on console:

```
create-dot-classpath:


BUILD FAILED
D:\pentaho-platform\user-console\build-res\subfloor.xml:2058:
Problem: failed to create task or type dot-classpath
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Please help me figure out how to build this one.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run create-dot-classpath. I build the user console all the time and have **never** run that. The comment in that task say "Creates the Eclipse .classpath file from the resolved classpath from Ant.". Try doing a build without that step and see what happens.

I usually run ant resolve (once) and then ant dist anytime I need to do a build.

Comment: I switched to master branch.. I only followed the instructions given here: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc2x/BI+Platform+7.0
will give a try to only ant resolve it. Can you guide me to build pentaho-platform? Thanks

Comment: There are guides written. Try building it and then ask specific questions, here or in the pentaho forums.

Comment: But I am trying to build it. The problem is I cannot resolve all the dependencies. Most of the versions/branches I already tried to build, but it seems that I cannot resolve them all.

Comment: You'll have to give lots more info.The version you're trying to build, your ant/maven version, your java version, the command you are running to build it, the error(s) you're getting, etc.etc